# Use of undeclared identifier 'true'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Why am I getting this error:

```
infinite.c:5:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'true'
    while (true) {

1 error generated.
make: *** [infinite] Error 1
```

... when I try to compile this simple code for an infinite loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 0;
    while (true) {
        printf("%i\n", x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better: `for (;;)`. No magic trivial conditions. And chances are that you can actually stick local declarations and the exit condition in there anyway.

Answer (score 61):

The identifier `true` is not declared by default. To use it, two solutions :

1. Compile in C99 and include `<stdbool.h>`.
2. Define this identifier by yourself.

However, the infinite loop `for (;;)` is often considered as better style.

Answer (score 28):

C has no built-in boolean types. So it doesn't know what `true` is. You have to declare it on your own in this way:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

[...]
while (TRUE) {
     [...]
}
```

Comment: C _has_ a built-in boolean type, it's called `_Bool`. To have the compiler know `true` and `false`, one has to `#include <stdbool.h>`, those are not built-in - but then you can also use `bool` instead of `_Bool` (which is a bit ugly).

Answer (score 5):

Include stdbool.h to use C99 booleans.
If you want to stick with C89 define it yourself:

```
typedef enum
{
    true=1, false=0
}bool;
```

Comment: If you don't have `stdbool.h` just stick to what that would do, namely give preprocessor defines for these values and not enumerations.

Comment: I think that preferring preprocessor defines over enums or viceversa is just a formality in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

You are Getting this error because you have not defined the values of true and false in C. You can do that by adding few simple lines to your code as follows:

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1 // Option 1
#define TRUE !FALSE // Option 2
```